# math functions sin and cos for angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

Hi I want to use sin and cos function in angularjs. I have searched about it and if you guys are having any other idea that how can implement sin and cos function in angularJs please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got both the function in javascript `Math.sin(x)` and `Math.cos(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use javascript `Math` Object:

```
 $scope.Math = Math;
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='OuterCtrl'>        
        {{Math.sin(3)}}        
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FG2n/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Angular for it, in javascript functions are [already there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) `Math.sin(x)`